# How to show full width video in exoplayer plugin in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Use this property in file but video was not display in full width which is shown below::

fill="true"

Comment: You will have to adjust your layout to let player take full screen.

Comment: how it's possible?? Can you share the screen..

Comment: As I mentioned, it totally depends on your layout. If you may share your component I might able to direct you.

Comment: If I used fill="aspectFill" property in exoplayer then video take full screen as per layout but video will be stretch..

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your width and height of layout . Also if any other parameter is reducing the layout size